# NetBeans IDE 6.9[.1] - Upload files on save - re-enable for session

Tags: ftp, netbeans, sftp

Periodically, when I am saving files, I get the error dialog `Upload files On Save failed. Disable this functionality for this session?`. Sometimes I accidentally select 'Yes'. How can I re-enable that functionality for the session without re-starting the IDE?

Comment: I've earned a tumbleweed badge for this one :(

Comment: This is still an issue in 6.9.1

Comment: Still no changes in 7.2?

Comment: @Alexey - I haven't gotten the error message in a long time, so I am not sure.

Comment: This is super annoying, Netbeans please add a feature to re-enable this!  Perfect place would be the Project > Right Click menu > Re-Enable FTP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a third solution that's related, and it's what I use now.

I use Atlassian SourceTree and its Git Flow implementation. While finishing hotfixes or releases, I actually don't want NetBeans to sync automatically. I've created a second configuration that I label "No Sync" for that purpose.

Simply switching to that configuration and then back to `<default>` re-enables syncing.

[image]

Answer (score 14):

I personally did not find any option to re-enable FTP Upload for session, but if you go to Project Properties and set in the Run Configuration "tab" the option Upload Files to "On Run" or "Manually", hit Ok, and then modify it again to "On Save", then the FTP Upload on save is enabled again.

Hope this was helpful!

Comment: As of 2017 this is the only method that works without having to restart project or IDE.

Comment: As of 2020 You can also close and re-open the project, or change the Run Configuration in project settings, as the other answers pointed out.

Answer (score 4):

I close and open the project on netbeans 7.3.
And syncing works again.
This is faster than restarting the IDE.

Comment: This worked for me. Netbeans 8.0